# Is there a twilio api to check if the numbers in my account are TollFree?

Tags: php, twilio

I have to check if the numbers in my account are TollFree. Does twilio has an api to filter the TollFree number?

Comment: Thank you for your time but that link didn't help me .

Answer (score 2):

You can send HTTP GET request to:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/{YourAccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers/TollFree
```

It will return a list of toll free number with paging information of your account.

Check [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/incoming-phone-numbers) for more.